# Binding an xml to a StackedColumns chart

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, charts, code-behind

I have two questions.
How do I construct my XML- file which i want to output in a Stacked Column chart using the code-behind?
And secondly, 
How do I put it in the code-behind in vb?

This is the code-behind at the moment:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Chart1.Width = 200
Chart1.Height = 300

Dim XMLFile As XElement = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/XMLFile.xml"))
Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
Chart1.Series(0).Palette = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel
Chart1.Series("Series1").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    For Each node As XElement In XMLFile.Elements("something")
        Dim string1 As String = node.Element("whatever1").Value
        Dim string2 As String = node.Element("whatever2").Value


        Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(string1, string2)
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Inclination = 15
        Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Rotation = 15
    Next
End Sub
```

The XMLFile looks something like this at the moment:

```
<root>
    <something>
        <whatever1>One</whatever1>
        <whatever2>1</whatever2>
    </something>
    <something>
        <whatever1>Two</whatever1>
        <whatever2>2</whatever2>
    </something>
</root>
```

I need two columns with three different values stacked in each column.
How do I do that?

Comment: You can read the XML in to a Dataset and append the datasource.

Comment: Thank you, but how should one construct the XML file to get three values into one stacked column?

Comment: There are hell lot of ways to bind datasource to Charts. Since , I thought you have the XML ready thats why. In that , you can use XMLDocument class to construct a proper XML or you can just write flat string in the XML format.

Comment: Thanks mate, I appriciate it!